# decimal point alignment and \pgfmathprintnumber

Tags: siunitx, pgfplotstable

In the table below, column a is aligned by decimal point. Is it possible to align column b that way too?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S S}
  a      & b                           \\
  -0.135 & \pgfmathprintnumber{-0.135} \\
  0.1    & \pgfmathprintnumber{0.1}    \\
  -0.1   & \pgfmathprintnumber{-0.1}   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\pgfmathprintnumber` is not expandable, so I don't think you can make it work inside an `S` column. I assume that the reason why you want to do this is that there are some calculations in the real world code? In that case, `xfp`'s `\fpeval` may be a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but have to use `dcolumn` instead of `siunitx`, below are the modified tags:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}%
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{d{2,3} d{2,3}}
  a      & b                           \\
  -0.135 & \pgfmathprintnumber{-0.135} \\
  0.1    & \pgfmathprintnumber{0.1}    \\
  -0.1   & \pgfmathprintnumber{-0.1}   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And the output is:

[image]